# NoClassDefFoundError : ConfigurationPropertySources

Tags: spring-boot, maven-2

Since yesterday we have a problem on our spring boot project after clean install without change nothing of configuration of the maven files, libs or something else.

We did try to update version of pom's of SpringFrameWork and Spring boot to 1.5.4.Release.

The error that is show is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/source/ConfigurationPropertySources
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.HostInfoEnvironmentPostProcessor.getFirstNonLoopbackHostInfo(HostInfoEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:46)
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.HostInfoEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(HostInfoEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:35)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:168)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:154)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:337)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at br.com.ibliss.auth.app.AuthServerApplication.main(AuthServerApplication.java:216)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySources
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 4):

According to [ConfigurationPropertySources source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/source/ConfigurationPropertySources.java), this class is around from version 2.0.0

> Provides access to {@link ConfigurationPropertySource ConfigurationPropertySources}.
>    @author Phillip Webb
>    **@since 2.0.0**

You probably did not upgrade your spring boot version but actually downgrade.