# Spring Boot Properties Migrator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to run an application(spring boot v1.5.9.0) with dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

and getting this error:

```
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/source/ConfigurationPropertySources
```

this error, apparently, did not occur before. How do I make the migrator work?

Do I have to change the spring-boot version to 2x before running the migrator? 
If so, i don't really get the migrator usage. 
As its scope is runtime - I have to make the app run before including it - which means I have to solve all the errors without migrator's advice? What do I use it for afterwards?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44654526/noclassdeffounderror-configurationpropertysources Check this too

Answer (score 2):

You've stated that you're running spring boot v1.5.9.0

It doesn't make sense to run the properties migrator with spring boot 1.5.x. Its primary intention is to "assist" in properties migrations that have changed during migration of spring boot 1.x to spring boot 2.x

As for the error, this specific class is available only since spring boot 2.0. See the comment `@since` in [the sourcefile](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/source/ConfigurationPropertySources.java)

Comment: I thought it was going to help me change the annotations, imports and so on before I change the version.. So it means I have to try running the application with 2.x version, handle all the errors and only then I would be able to see the migrator output? It doesnt really make sense to me. Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: No. You run it with a new versions but with old properties. It helps to migrate since many properties have changed between spring boot 1.x and 2.x. Its an auxiliary tool.

Answer (score 0):

In your project, `application.properties` or `application.yml` is present or not? `Spring boot` is `auto-configuration`. I think those properties will be expecting..Also check what are the `annotations` used in `Spring boot` main class..Share that `Spring boot main class` as well..will check